# JOIN 2 Table SQL Server with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem here.

I have 2 tables want to join with `group by.`

```
tbl_1
NO userID users status branchID
 1   1   abc   ok      2
 2   2   da    ok      1
 3   3   fe     ok     3
4    1   abc    ok     1
5    3   fe     ok      2

tbl_2
branchID   branch
2           medan
1           jakarta
3           batam
```

I need to show the user and the branch based on `branchID`, I think this will use group by. How to do that?

I want the output is not duplicate users show, when do select.

```
output
user   branch
abc    medan,jakarta
fe     medan,batam
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to aggregate?

Comment: Add your desired output

Comment: what is your desired result.?

Comment: Please, do not just explain what you want in the output – **show** your output (in the question).

Comment: @AndriyMI already add the output, please help

Comment: @ChiragThakar I already add output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isnt very elegant but will do the job based on your data and output

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users,
            STUFF(( 
                    SELECT ', ' + branch
                      FROM(
                    SELECT DISTINCT Users,
                                    branch
                      FROM #tbl_1 t1
                           INNER JOIN #tbl_2 t2 ON t1.branchID = t2.branchID ) A
                      WHERE A.users = T.users
                      FOR XML PATH( '' )),1,2,'' ) AS Branches
FROM #tbl_1 T;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  select t1.users , t2.branch
  from tbl_1 t1 inner join tbl_2 t2
  on t1.branchID=t2.branchID
  group by t1.users , t2.branch;
```

Comment: Hi and how do you know that OP wants to group "t1.users , t2.branch"

Comment: To fetch USERS and BRANCH from respective tables......If I dont use GROUP BY here then there will be duplicates in result.

Comment: But you can even group by it with "status".. My question is OP did not mention anything clearly. So add a word stating that your doing it with assumption in mind.

Comment: I just answered the requirement - " I need to show the user and the branch based on branchID ". What is the need of including "STATUS" in query?

Comment: because the user did not mention anything about the aggr and group by select statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct tbl_1.userID, tbl_1.users, tbl_1.status, tbl_1.branchID, tbl_2.branch
from tbl_1
left join tbl_2
on tbl.branchID = tbl_2.branchID
```

this will only show you all the field that have different value.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.